# Aligning a Shimano direct mount derailleur

Tags: derailleur, alignment, hanger

I was suffering bad shifting and skips and my derailleur appeared to be bent slightly inwards, so I thought I’d check it with a Park DAG 2.2 I already owned (for a previous bike).

Instead of the hanger I expected it looks like I’ve got a “direct mount”? I haven’t come across this before, the derailleur is attached to this black piece (bracket axle?) with the smaller bolt I’m holding - not M10.

Can it still be aligned with Park DAG? Should I be trying to bend the black piece (in which case, do I need some kind of adapter to fit the smaller thread), or the hanging bit of frame?

[image: derailleur mount]
*Apologies for the orientation - top of image is the rear of the bike*

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a normal derailleur mount (in silver: part of the frame) under the black mount. You have simply undone the wrong bolt. Take off your black part currently attached to the frame and use the Park tool in that.

Comment: Thanks, yeah you’re right. I’m surprised there isn’t a separate sacrificial hanger, I thought that was pretty standard. (Touring bike - Ridgeback expedition. Not dirt cheap!).

Comment: @RobHogan Sacrificial hanger is not required for steel, it doesn't crack when you bend it!